# Setting a table with td width as a %

Tags: html, css

I am creating a table and would like to set the width of the column to be a specific %, for example 10%, regardless of the number of columns. The table is generated from a query and so may have 1 column or it may have 5. Either way I would like the width of each to be the specific % width. For example, using the this html with `css` of width='10%'

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class='width10'> ....... </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

but this does not display as 10% into the page, more like 30%.

Strangely if I change it to 5% width it goes to about 50% of the page, if I set it at 25% it goes to about 5%.

Comment: As far as I know that's not possible, however from the server side language, you may be able to always print 10 <td>s even if some of them are empty.

Answer (score 0):

When you set width using a percent you are setting it as the percent of the containing element, not the page/viewport/whatever you thought.

Therefore, it dosen't make any sense to set TD's using %, because it will always be % of the `<tr>/<table>` and the table gets it's width from the td's.

use something else. OR, set the table width explicity :)

```
<table style="width:100%;">
```

---

based on our conversation, this is what you were looking for..

```
<div style="width:100%">
<div class='border width10'> ....... </div>
<div class='border width10'> ....... </div>
<div class='border width10'> ....... </div>
</div>

.width10 {
    width: 10%;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0
}
.border {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: I have tried that but if I put the table as 100% then the column spans the complete page, regardless of setting the <td> as 10%. However I didn't know that <table> gets its width from the <td>.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle so i can see :)